# Problem when deploy object in salesforce

Tags: custom-object, deployment, error

Did anyone can help me ?
Why when i deploy an object from my production into sandbox, always error.

The error message : in Field: searchResultsField - no CustomField named PYSETINSURANCE__c.FKTP_Code__c found

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying to deploy a changeset from production to sandbox, in your outbound changeset, there are one or more components (e.g. trigger, visualforce page, apex class etc.) referring the `FKTP_Code__c` field of `PYSETINSURANCE__c` object which has not been added.

So, add that field and re-deploy the changeset.

For more info, [Change Set Error message](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004207&language=en_US)

Comment: nice to hear that